# What's the right way to configure Angular 9 e2e cobertura coverage reports?

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, angular9, cobertura, karma-coverage

We need to have cobertura style coverage reports in our Angular 9 application.  I'm trying to configure our end to end tests to generate such reports.  I installed **karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter** v 2.1.0 and added the following configuration to *karma.conf.js*

```
plugins: [
    ...
    require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
client: {
  clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
},
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
  dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/OurProject'),
  reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary', 'cobertura'],
  fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
},
```

However in our *package.json* file, when I add `--codeCoverage=true` options

```
{
  ...
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "npm run install-puppeteer && ng e2e --codeCoverage=true"
  },
```

I get the following error when running the `npm run e2e` ...

```
Unknown option: '--codeCoverage'
```

What's the right way to configure our e2e tests to generate cobertura coverage reports?

Comment: `--codeCoverage` is indeed not listed [in the CLI docs](https://angular.io/cli/e2e). Coverage tends to be more relevant for _unit_ tests (which is what `karma.conf.js` is for), it's supported in `ng test`: https://angular.io/guide/testing-code-coverage. It looks like there are [no plans](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6286) for the CLI to support coverage in E2E.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are trying to use applies for Unit testing for which karma is used. But --codeCoverage option is not available with e2e. For e2e test we use protractor in angular. For that you could use something like **[protractor-istanbul-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-istanbul-plugin)**

It can be included in your protractor.conf.js like below :-

```
plugins : [{
      path: 'node_modules/protractor-istanbul-plugin'
    }]
```

It will create a coverage folder after your e2e test run. to see its html report use command :-

```
istanbul report --include=coverage/*.json
```

For more details visit :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-istanbul-plugin